# python.exe crashes down while interpreting 'read_csv' command of pandas library

Tags: csv, pandas

I am currently working on a collaborative project which requires use of *ipython notebook* and *pandas library*. I have saved a pandas dataframe into a **csv** file on the remote server using the following code:

```
z.to_csv("z.csv", sep=';', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

I want to use this file locally. So, I have downloaded the file and used it as an input using the following code line:

```
z=pd.read_csv('z.csv',sep=';',low_memory=False,error_bad_lines=False)
```

But whenever the interpreter encounters this line it crashes down with the message- "Python.exe has stopped working."

I have toggled around with some parameters like index, low_memory, index, index_col, error_bad_lines but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone has idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Does just `z=pd.read_csv('z.csv',sep=';')` work? (Is there a reason you add ``low_memory=False,error_bad_lines=False``?)

Comment: @joris No,  it encounters the same problem.  I added ` low_memory=False` because the file is quite big, around 300 MB. I also tried by adding `error_bad_lines=False` as I thought that there might be some problematic lines in the file which will be eliminated by this option.